# Writing data bigger than page size into shared memory

Tags: c++, shared-memory, mmap

My processor has its page size as 4096. I need to write data into shared memory and this data has a size 7168 (7 KB). 
I used the ftruncate and allocated 8192 (2*page_size) so that there would be sufficient memory.

```
shmem_fd = shm_open( TRIAL_SHMEM_FILE, O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if( shmem_fd == -1 ) 
{
    printf("Create_shmem, open failed:%s",strerror( errno));PASLOG  return false;
}
if( ftruncate( shmem_fd, 8192) == -1 )
{
    printf("Create_shmem, ftruncate failed:%s",strerror( errno));PASLOG return false;
}
```

I am writing the structure as below. [767*10]bytes is lesser than [2*page_size]. But the below code causes a segmentation fault. 
If I try to write [767*5] which is within [1-page_size] there is no crash. I am unable to know the actual cause of the crash. Is there a different way to proceed?

```
// data to be written into shared memory
list_data item[10]; // struct size is 767 bytes
for (uiCounter=DEFAULT_VALUE_ZERO; uiCounter < 10; ++uiCounter)
{
    memset(&item[uiCounter], 0, sizeof(list_data));
}           

list_data* list_shmem;
list_shmem = (list_data *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(list_data) * 10, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmem_fd, 0 );

if(list_shmem == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("mmap failsed: %s", strerror(errno));
    return false;
}

// write to shared mem
for (uiCounter = DEFAULT_VALUE_ZERO; uiCounter < 10; ++uiCounter)
{
    memcpy ( list_shmem, &item[uiCounter], sizeof(person) );
    ++list_shmem;
}

munmap(list_shmem, sizeof(list_data) * 10);
```

Comment: Can you debug the program step by step and find the exact line that is causing segfault?

Comment: The seffault happens in the  memcpy ( list_shmem, &item[uiCounter], sizeof(list_data) ); line always when the counter is 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. You pass a wrong address to `munmap` in:

   ```
   list_data* list_shmem;
   list_shmem = (list_data *) mmap(...);

   for (uiCounter = DEFAULT_VALUE_ZERO; uiCounter < 10; ++uiCounter)
   {
       memcpy ( list_shmem, &item[uiCounter], sizeof(person) );
       ++list_shmem; // <---- invalidates list_shmem original value
   }

   munmap(list_shmem, sizeof(list_data) * 10);
   ```
2. You specify wrong size to `memcpy` in:

   ```
   memcpy ( list_shmem, &item[uiCounter], sizeof(person) );
   ```

   A fix is:

   ```
   memcpy ( list_shmem, &item[uiCounter], sizeof(item[uiCounter]) );
   ```

---

One fix for both issues would be to use standard algorithm [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead of the hand-coded loop:

```
    std::copy(item + DEFAULT_VALUE_ZERO, item + 10, list_shmem);
```

---

Bonus point:

```
list_data item[10]; // struct size is 767 bytes
for (uiCounter=DEFAULT_VALUE_ZERO; uiCounter < 10; ++uiCounter)
{
    memset(&item[uiCounter], 0, sizeof(list_data));
}
```

Is the same as:

```
list_data item[10] = {};
```

Comment: @BЈовић Because you change `list_shmem` and then pass it to `munmap`.

Comment: I see your point with the memcpy, that error was due to the sample code I placed here. But what is the issue with munmap

Comment: @BlueBottle Pay attention to line `++list_shmem; // <---- invalidates list_shmem original value`. But you never notice it because you do not check the return value of `munmap`.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that. I need to know now why I am not able to write more than 4096 bytes at a time.

Comment: _I need to know now why I am not able to write more than 4096 bytes at a time_ - you should be able to.